# Best way to get all documents from mobile?

Tags: android, android-cursor

I want to get all types of documents pdf,xml,doc except video and image and audio files.

And display list with name, size, date, and location.

```
       ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

    // every column, although that is huge waste, you probably need
    // BaseColumns.DATA (the path) only.
    String[] projection = null;

// exclude media files, they would be here also.
String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
        + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_NONE;
String[] selectionArgs = null; // there is no ? in selection so null here

String sortOrder = null; // unordered
Cursor allNonMediaFiles = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

I am using this code for getting documents from mobile is it work? And how to get the document details like uri, date, and name. thanks advance.

Comment: I edited my question please check -- @gnat

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
File path;
ArrayList<String> pdf_paths=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> pdf_names=new ArrayList<String>();
path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "");
searchFolderRecursive1(path);

private static void searchFolderRecursive1(File folder)
{
   if (file.isFile())
     {
      //.pdf files 
      if(file.getName().contains(".pdf"))
      {
       file.getPath();
       pdf_names.add(file.getName());
       pdf_paths.add(file.getPath());
       Log.e("pdf_paths", ""+pdf_names);
      }
      else if(file.getName().contains(".doc"))
      {
       file.getPath();
       pdf_names.add(file.getName());
       pdf_paths.add(file.getPath());
      }
    }   
  }
```

Comment: This methods also to be return name and location

Answer (score -2):

String ext =FilenameUtils.getExtension(mediSore.getString(mediSore.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA)));
                if(ext.equals("pdf") || ext.equals("txt")|| ext.equals("docx") ||
                        ext.equals("xlsx") ||
                        ext.equals("csv")||
                        ext.equals("ods")||
                        ext.equals("odt")
                        ) {
                    Array.add(
                            mediSore.getString(mediSore.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA)) + " -- " +
                                    mediSore.getString(mediSore.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.TITLE)) + "---" +
                                    mediSore.getString(mediSore.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME))
                    );

---

### Heading